# Android - Is it possible to overwrite userdata of another app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to update user data of another app from my app. The purpose of this is to update some images that the other app uses. Is this possible?

Comment: Are these images that the app uses internally or images that are saved somewhere on the device?

Comment: Location where i want update data is  /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.xbmc.kodi/files/.kodi/userdata/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where the data/images are saved.

For every app there is a folder named **/android/data/package.name** to which only that application has access to read and write. No other application has the privilege of writing to that particular folder.

But if the data is saved somewhere else than **/android/data/package.name** folder, then you can definitely overwrite their data giving that you have proper  read/write permissions.

Comment: The folder where i want to write data is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.xbmc.kodi/files/.kodi/userdata/

Comment: As you can see that this is the exact folder where the data belonging to this particular application is written. So you don't have the right to overwrite this data.

Comment: What if the phone or device is rooted ?